# How to initialize a WebSocket Endpoint with constructor parameters

Tags: java, java-websocket

I am using `javax.websocket.*` API right now but I don't know how to initialize an `Endpoint` with some constructor parameters after searching on the Internet.

```
ServerContainer container = WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context); //jetty
container.addEndpoint(MyWebSocketEndpoint.class);
```

I want pass through some parameters when initializing `MyWebSocketEndpoint` then I can use the parameter, say `clientQueue`, in my `onOpen` method doing something like:

```
clientQueue.add(new Client(session));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `ServerContainer.addEndpoint(ServerEndpointConfig)` and need a `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` implementation to make this work.

First create a custom `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` class which acts as factory for your endpoint:

```
public class MyWebSocketEndpointConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {
    private ClientQueue clientQueue_;

    public MyWebSocketEndpoint(ClientQueue clientQueue) {
        clientQueue_ = clientQueue;
    }

    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException {
        return (T)new MyWebSocketEndpoint(clientQueue_);
    }
}
```

and then register it on the `ServerContainer`:

```
ClientQueue clientQueue = ...
ServerContainer container = ...
container.addEndpoint(ServerEndpointConfig.Builder
    .create(MyWebSocketEndpoint.class, "/") // the endpoint url
    .configurator(new MyWebSocketEndpointConfigurator(clientQueue _))
    .build());
```

Comment: This is rather confusing. 
In the first section you have a constructor for MyWebSocketEndpoint declared as a member of MyWebSocketEndpointConfigurator.
Then in the second section you seem to be trying to reference the private clientQueue, although there's  a space before the underscore. Or maybe you're referencing the local one but mistyped it?